# How to use firefox preferences in addon as an array?

Tags: module, firefox-addon, preferences, commonjs

I've been searching throughout the internet for a way to use firefox's preference engine to store arrays in an addon. The extension I am trying to build would need to maintain an array map, with each entry containing 2 values, but it is extremely hard to manually code that in the extension. I was wondering if anyone new of either an API or module that can create that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you encode the array as JSON and store the JSON string in the preference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using JSON to encode a lot of my add-on preferences now. There is no performance hit for the length of your strings in the preferences. It's a great way to do exactly what you are trying to do.